# get rows only contains specific value in a specific column in Interactive Grid in oracle apex 20.1 with plsql or javascript

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.1

I want to find rows of a interactive grid with specific column value. For an example in this employee interactive grid, i want to get all the rows with EMP Status "Active". Also I wanna know if the row is modified.. Is it possible with js or PL/SQL.?

```
emp name | emp status
-------- |------------
Jane        Active
-------- |------------
Doe         Inactive
-------- |------------
Helan       Active
-------- |------------
```

Answer (score 0):

**Filter on EMP Status**
You've got two options to filter on an `Active` employee status

- Filter in de sql query to restrict the user from only seeing active employees `where emp_status = 'Active'`
- Filter using the Interactive Grid 'out-of-the-box' filter options, to let the user filter on a value in a specific column. Select the arrow next to the magnifier icon to select a specific column to filter on.

**Check if row is updated**
To check whether or not a row has been updated in the Interactive Grid, you can use javascript code below:

```
var grid = apex.region("omi_Tabular_grid").call('getViews','grid');

grid.model.forEach( function(r, i, k){
                      console.log( i, grid.model.getRecordMetadata(k).updated);
                    })
```